# ViewController does not load its xib file in localized app Whenever I delete and re-install?

Tags: ios, localization, xib

My application is not loading its xib files after deleting and re installing the application in the simulator.

The application works well before enabling the localization, loading xibs after every time I delete and re-install it.

My application is working fine without a problem after adding support for another language(Localization).But if I choose to delete and re-install It is loading my initial window and the default viewcontroller(Single View application Template) only.

help me out friends

Comment: Have you tried performing a clean build? Stop & uninstall your app, perform the Clean build action in Xcode, then build and install it as normal.

Comment: @Tim Yes But still No xibs get loaded

Comment: @Tim it is working after I quit and reopen Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all Working after several delete and re-installing the app from the simulator, But it start worked after I quit and open my Xcode